# Android Kotlin with Native NDK C Code into WebAssembly with Kotlin Multiplatform

Tags: kotlin, webassembly, kotlin-multiplatform

As a complete noob to **Kotlin Multiplatform** I am wondering if there is a way to export (a part of) an existing Android Application that consists of **Kotlin Code as well as C** code (OpenCV graphics and own filters and analysis, **via Android NDK/JNI**) to other platforms (in our case WebAssembly) using Kotlin Multiplatform.

While trying to set it up I am stuck with the "**System.loadLibrary("native-lib")**" part to load the native library from Kotlin code. There is no such thing as "System" for the other platforms as it is an Android thing.
Whats the equivalent on other platforms or is there a more platform independent way to load the C library? Is it the completely wrong approach?

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, or more generally any Kotlin/Native platform, you could do this with KMP, although you'll need to change how the 2 sides talk to each other. Kotlin/Native generates interop code from C headers that Kotlin/Native can call, but it's different than how Kotlin/JVM talks to JNI (for example, `System.loadLibrary` is JVM-only and wouldn't be called for either WASM or Kotlin/Native).

There was support for WASM in Kotlin/Native, but the team has abandoned that in favor of an entirely new compiler for WASM. There was a technical preview recently, but I would imagine the work needed to have Kotlin/WASM interop with C/WASM is significant and still TBD. You *may* have better luck with the older Kotlin/Native WASM target, as it might support Kotlin/Native's cinterop, but I would guess that would be fairly difficult to do, especially if you're new to KMP (and I suspect it would not be possible currently, but I could be wrong about that).